# Event log shows Windows wakes up from prolonged sleeps (8 hrs), but monitors and keyboard don't respond; shorter sleeps work (5 minutes)

Tags: windows, windows-10, sleep

I have a Windows 10 install that has been behaving correctly for the past few years, waking up from sleep quickly and easily whether it has been off for a minute or for days.

Recently, it only wakes up correctly from shorter sleeps. I'm not quite sure how long Windows needs to sleep before it won't wake up correctly, but it seems to be at least a few hours. It doesn't Hibernate (unless explicitly told) as this is turned off in the Advanced Settings of Power Options.

When it doesn't correctly wake up (by just moving the mouse) I've noticed the following:

- Fans spin up immediately
- Keyboard num-lock led comes on
- Event log in Windows registers the wake up (events like time synchronization get written)

Then nothing further happens, the monitors stay in their sleep state, and the keyboard is unresponsive (can't toggle num-lock or caps-lock leds); resetting the graphics driver key combination (Ctrl+Shift+Windows+B) doesn't do anything.

As the event log is working (which I can check after doing a hard power-off), I suspect the computer is at least partially awake and may be visible on the network and perhaps even respond to it.

Note that I have Windows updates off and haven't updated any drivers or even installed any new software. The system setup has been similar for at least the past few months when it was working correctly.

Any ideas what may be causing Windows to not wake up correctly from prolonged sleep periods?

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the problem.

First, there was another indication there was a problem: the power LED on the machine remained on when the machine was put to sleep (normally it would blink).

I then changed two things, one of which probably solved my problem:

1. I turned off PWM mode in the Bios for one of the chassis fans
2. In advanced power settings ("Power Options"), I changed the USB Selective Suspend Setting to `Enabled`

I hope this is useful to someone else.